# xsl/xml moving elements in the same node

Tags: xml, xls

I have a question. Now I would like to move the elements in the same node.

I have this

```html
<test>
- <invoice>
   <id>163-01</id>
   <date>2016-09-06</date>
   <cadreLegal>LAB</cadreLegal>
   <prestataire>907</prestataire>
   <personneProtegee>1951</personneProtegee>
   <dateEtablissement>2016-09-06</dateEtablissement>
   <heureEtablissement>13:22:00</heureEtablissement> 
 </invoice>
- <invoice>
   <id>163-01</id>
   <date>2016-09-06</date>
   <cadreLegal>LAB</cadreLegal>
   <prestataire>907</prestataire>
   <personneProtegee>1951</personneProtegee>
   <dateEtablissement>2016-09-06</dateEtablissement>
   <heureEtablissement>13:22:00</heureEtablissement>
 </invoice>
</test>
```

I would lie to move "id" to the last position in the node.

```html
<test>
- <invoice>
   <date>2016-09-06</date>
   <cadreLegal>LAB</cadreLegal>
   <prestataire>907</prestataire>
   <personneProtegee>1951</personneProtegee>
   <dateEtablissement>2016-09-06</dateEtablissement>
   <heureEtablissement>13:22:00</heureEtablissement> 
   <id>163-01</id>
 </invoice>
- <invoice>
   <date>2016-09-06</date>
   <cadreLegal>LAB</cadreLegal>
   <prestataire>907</prestataire>
   <personneProtegee>1951</personneProtegee>
   <dateEtablissement>2016-09-06</dateEtablissement>
   <heureEtablissement>13:22:00</heureEtablissement>
   <id>163-01</id>
 </invoice>
</test>
```

I tried this code and it work just fine (after some research).

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 
<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
 
<xsl:template match="order">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
 
<xsl:template match="invoice">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="cadreLegal|prestatairePrescripteur | personneProtegee | dateEtablissement | heureEtablissement "/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="id "/>
  </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.